# Why some matches in give 4,000 points while some give much less?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I don't understand how to get the maximum possible score. Making special candies doesn't seem the best strategy. Sometimes a sequence of matches in a single move seems to yield better results. But I didn't find in the internet any information about how the points works in this case

Comment: I found out that when there's jelly with the candy, it gives around a thousand points for its destruction

Comment: V Answers go down there V

Comment: @Batophobia I know, but this doesn't explain I sometimes I get 12,000 points for a 3-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a **lot** more points when you make progress towards objectives. This includes (but is not limited to) clearing jelly, diffusing bombs, and bringing ingredients to the bottom. Those objectives garner even more points when they're triggered via a chain reaction; the more chains, the more the points are multiplied.